# Total count of advanced custom field values in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get the total count of a value of a custom field for WooCommerce products. My products are stock of shoes, so for each product I create a custom field for the total pairs quantity. Now I need to display in a new page the total count of pairs.

I tried with this code but the result is always 0

```
<?php 
$pair_total = 0; //my main variable
$posts = get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page'  => -1,      //get all post
'post_type'     => 'product' //my custom post type
));

if( $posts ) {     
        
    foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
    
      setup_postdata( $post );
      if (get_field('n_totale')) {
        echo get_field('n_totale'); //show individual field(not needed)
        $pair_total = get_field('n_totale') + $pair_total;    //sum all fields 
      }
    }      
  
   wp_reset_postdata(); 

 }?>

  <?php echo '<h1>'.$pair_total.'</h1>'//showing the total value;
  ?>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

check [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) Try below code.

```
<?php 

$pair_total = 0; //my main variable

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,      //get all post
    'post_type'      => 'product' //my custom post type
));

if( $posts ) {     
    foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
        setup_postdata( $post );
        if ( get_field( 'n_totale', get_the_ID() ) ) {
            $pair_total = $pair_total + (int) get_field('n_totale', get_the_ID() );    //sum all fields 
        }
    }      
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}   

echo '<h1>'.$pair_total.'</h1>'//showing the total value;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it however output 0. I don't understand, it's look like it can't retireve the value of the custom field. What I can try next?

Comment: Did you check this condition `if ( get_field( 'n_totale', get_the_ID() ) ) {` is true or false?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code:

```
$pair_total_1 = 0; //my main variable

$posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts' => -1,      //get all post, previously was post_per_page
'post_type'      => 'product', //my custom post type
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '=',
    )
)   //I add a query to count only in stock product 
 ));
if( $posts ) {  
global $post;
foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
    setup_postdata( $post);
    if ( get_field( 'n_totale', get_the_ID() ) ) {
        $pair_total_1 = $pair_total_1 + (int) get_field('n_totale', get_the_ID() );    
 //sum all fields 
    }
}      
wp_reset_postdata(); 
}

 echo '<p>Totale paia disponibili: '.$pair_total_1.'</p>';}//showing the total value
```

Thanks to all